# How do I parse out a ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.APIObject[] array via AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to figure out how to parse a WSDL.APIObject[] array. So, I have a landing page with this:

```
%%[
  /* display list of automations in account */
  SET @rr_1=CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
  SetObjectProperty(@rr_1,"ObjectType","Automation")
  AddObjectArrayItem(@rr_1,"Properties","Name")

  SET @sfp=CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
  SetObjectProperty(@sfp,"Property","Status")
  SetObjectProperty(@sfp,"SimpleOperator","equals")
  AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp,"Value","1")
  SetObjectProperty(@rr_1,"Filter",@sfp)

  SET @automations=InvokeRetrieve(@rr_1)
]%%

<html>
  <body>
    %%=v(@automations)=%%
  </body>
</html>
```

@automations output as

ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.APIObject[]

When I run the equivalent SOAP envelope in SOAP UI I get a collection of automations. I can't seem to find much in way of AMPScript API documentation on ways to be able to parse out the array that's returned.

Comment: Typically I have found that SSJS has slightly more functionality for handling objects and arrays. Have you had a look at that option?

Answer (score 3):

You need to display each element of the array in a loop.

```
SET @automationsCount = RowCount(@automations)
IF @automationsCount > 0 THEN
    FOR @i = 1 TO @automationsCount DO
        Set @name = Field(Row(@automations, @i),"Name")
        OutputLine(Concat('Automation name: ', @name))
    NEXT @i
ENDIF
```

Reference:

- [**Row**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/row.htm)
- [**Field**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/field.htm)
- [**For**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm)